# Texture not filling the entire render target view on resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, directx-11, sharpdx

I'm trying to implement the resizing of render target when window/control is resized.

However when doing so it is not working as expected (maybe cause i'm not doing it correctly) as the rendered texture is not filling my entire render target view.

Now, when ever the window is resized, i reset my render target view and any other render target (texture) [Please see code below]

```
        this.ImgSource.SetRenderTargetDX11(null);

        Disposer.SafeDispose(ref this.m_RenderTargetView);
        Disposer.SafeDispose(ref this.m_d11Factory);
        Disposer.SafeDispose(ref this.RenderTarget);

        int width = (int)sizeInfo.Width;
        int height = (int)sizeInfo.Height;

        Texture2DDescription colordesc = new Texture2DDescription
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Format = PIXEL_FORMAT,
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            MipLevels = 1,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.Shared,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            ArraySize = 1

        };

        this.RenderTarget = new Texture2D(this.Device, colordesc);
        m_RenderTargetView = new RenderTargetView(this.Device, this.RenderTarget);

        m_depthStencil = CreateTexture2D(this.Device, width, height, BindFlags.DepthStencil, Format.D24_UNorm_S8_UInt);

        m_depthStencilView = new DepthStencilView(this.Device, m_depthStencil);

        Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(0, 0, width, height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(m_depthStencilView, m_RenderTargetView);

        SetShaderAndVertices(sizeInfo);
```

SetShaderAndVertices Method: (sizeInfo is the size of he render target)

```
   protected void SetShaderAndVertices(Size rendersize)
    {
        var device = this.Device;
        var context = device.ImmediateContext;

        ShaderBytecode shaderCode = GetShaderByteCode(eEffectType.Texture);
        layout = new InputLayout(device, shaderCode, new[] {
               new InputElement("SV_Position", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
                new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, Format.R32G32_Float, 32, 0),
        });

        // Write vertex data to a datastream
        var stream = new DataStream(Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionTexture>() * 4, true, true);

        stream.WriteRange(new[]
                            {
                        new VertexPositionTexture(
                                    new Vector4(-1, 1, 0.0f, 1.0f), // position top-left
                                    new Vector2(0f,0f)
                                    ),
                        new VertexPositionTexture(
                                    new Vector4(1, 1, 0.0f, 1.0f), // position top-right
                                    new Vector2(1,0)
                                    ),
                        new VertexPositionTexture(
                                    new Vector4(-1, -1, 0.0f, 1.0f), // position bottom-left
                                     new Vector2(0,1)
                                    ),
                        new VertexPositionTexture(
                                    new Vector4(1, -1, 0.0f, 1.0f), // position bottom-right
                                     new Vector2(1,1)
                                    ),
                              });
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Instantiate VertexPositionTexture buffer from vertex data
        // 
        vertices = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(device, stream, new BufferDescription()
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SizeInBytes = Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionTexture>() * 4,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            StructureByteStride = 0
        });
        stream.Dispose();

        // Prepare All the stages
        // for primitive topology https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx#ID4E2BAC
        context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = (layout);
        context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = (PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip);
        context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertices, Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionTexture>(), 0));

        context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(m_RenderTargetView);
    }
```

**Shader File**:

```
Texture2D ShaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState Sampler : register(s0);

cbuffer PerObject: register(b0)
{
    float4x4 WorldViewProj;
};


// ------------------------------------------------------
// A shader that accepts Position and Texture
// ------------------------------------------------------

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VSMain(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output = (VertexShaderOutput)0;

    output.Position = input.Position;
    output.TextureUV = input.TextureUV;

    return output;
}

float4 PSMain(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_Target
{
    return ShaderTexture.Sample(Sampler, input.TextureUV);
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
// A shader that accepts Position and Color
// ------------------------------------------------------

struct ColorVS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_Position;
    float4 col : COLOR;
};

struct ColorPS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_Position;
    float4 col : COLOR;
};

ColorPS_IN ColorVS(ColorVS_IN input)
{
    ColorPS_IN output = (ColorPS_IN)0;
    output.pos = input.pos;
    output.col = input.col;
    return output;
}

float4 ColorPS(ColorPS_IN input) : SV_Target
{
    return input.col;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Techniques
// ------------------------------------------------------

technique11 Color
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetGeometryShader(0);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, ColorVS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, ColorPS()));
    }
}

technique11 TextureLayer
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetGeometryShader(0);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, VSMain()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, PSMain()));
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to either stretch the image or not thus maintaining the aspect ratio based on my requirement.

Also my texture data is updated from another thread via mapping the bitmap data to my render target.

Note: Texture fills the entire render target view if the mapped image is of same size as my rendered target view.

Please see screen dumps below:

Screenshots:
1st Screen:

[image]

Size for 1st screen dump image:
---- Display Image size (835, 626) on render target of Size(720, 576)

2nd Screen:

[image]

Size for 2nd screen dump image:
 Display Image size (899, 674) on render target of Size(899, 676)

Any more information then do let me know and I will happily provide.

Thanks.

P.S:
I have also posted this question in [another forum](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/673339-texture-not-filling-the-entire-render-target-view-on-resizing/) but had no luck hence posting here hoping someone would be able to direct me in the correct direction.

Using C# , SharpDx with Directx11 and D3DImage && not using Swapchains

Also see below is the code used to map texture data:
        Device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(this.m_RenderTargetView, Color4.Black);

```
        Texture2DDescription colordesc = new Texture2DDescription
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Format = PIXEL_FORMAT,
            Width = iWidthOfImage,
            Height = iHeightOfImage,
            MipLevels = 1,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write,
            ArraySize = 1
        };

        Texture2D newFrameTexture = new Texture2D(this.Device, colordesc);

        DataStream dtStream = null;
        DataBox dBox = Device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(newFrameTexture, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, 0, out dtStream);
        if (dtStream != null)
        {
            int iRowPitch = dBox.RowPitch;

            for (int iHeightIndex = 0; iHeightIndex < iHeightOfImage; iHeightIndex++)
            {
                //Copy the image bytes to Texture
                // we write row strides multiplies by bytes per pixel
                // as our case is bgra32 which is 4 bytes 
                dtStream.Position = iHeightIndex * iRowPitch;
                Marshal.Copy(decodedData, iHeightIndex * iWidthOfImage * 4, new IntPtr(dtStream.DataPointer.ToInt64() + iHeightIndex * iRowPitch), iWidthOfImage * 4);
            }
        }

        Device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(newFrameTexture, 0);
        Device.ImmediateContext.CopySubresourceRegion(newFrameTexture, 0, null, this.RenderTarget, 0);
```

Comment: You seem to have a wrong understanding of the coordinate system. You need to define your quad in clip space, which has coordinates in the range `[-1, 1]` (left to right, bottom to top). It does not use pixel coordinates. The texture coordinates are in the range `[0, 1]` (left to right, top to bottom). No pixel coordinates either. This lets you specify the quad independently of the screen resolution. Finally, you don't need six vertices for a triangle-strip forming a quad. Four are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @NicoSchertler However after updating the code as suggested by yourself my problem still holds regarding the resizing. Any suggestions on that ? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the current code.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have updated the code with the suggested changes

Answer (score 0):

After resizing, your new window's aspect ratio doesn't match your texture, so it can't cover the entire client area of the window.  You'll have to enlarge the textured geometry so that it covers the entire client area when projected onto the camera plane.  This will necessarily mean that a portion of the texture is clipped.

Basically, this is the same problem when watching 4:3 aspect ratio TV programming on a 16:9 monitor.  You can either zoom it to fill the screen, whereby the 4:3 content is cropped or stretched, or you can letter box the 4:3 content with black on either side of the content.

Comment: Thanks for the information @legalize however how would I stretch/shrink the texture without clipping the texture or displaying the texture as letter box content which is my problem here as I'm new to directx11. Any pseudo code or actual code would really be helpful.

Comment: I missed that you also have multithreading going on.  Simplify this down to the smallest possible program that you can.  That means no multithreading.  I would further simplify the texture to be a giant square checkerboard so it is easier to see if distortion is being introduced and if the non-square texture dimension is causing something to go wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @legalize it has helped me identify the problem. I we actually updating the view port from a different thread in contrast to the render. I now set the viewport and any other resources if my render size changes. Thanks